# generate count data that looks like the gamma curve

Tags: r, simulation

I need to simulate (positive) outcome data that, plotted against time, looks somewhat like the gamma curve (the typical positively skewed form), see the picture linked below to get an idea.

so simply generating random numbers in R by e.g.:

```
n <- 21
x <- rGA(n, 3, 3)
y <- rPO(n, x)
```

wont work, since there should be some autoregressive pattern / error included.

So is there a way to account for the noise

```
 y <- rPO(n, x) + eps # where eps[t] = rho *  eps[t]
```

in a similar way like this?

Best regards,
Aiho

[image: example data]

Comment: do the `?dgamma` set of functions help you get a gamma distribution you are looking for? something like `plot(dgamma(1:100,20))`?

Comment: @Mike unfortunately that is not what I am looking for. The scatter plot of the data (time against counts) should be shaped in a similar way as the gamma curve (just like the linked example data)

Answer (score 1):

I think Mike meant something like:

```
x <- 1:21
y1 <- dgamma(x, 2.5, 0.3)
y2 <- rpois(length(x), y1 * 20000)
plot(x, y2, 'b')
```

your data looks more dispersed than Poisson, so maybe do:

```
y2 <- rnbinom(length(x), mu=y1 * 20000, size=100)
```

this is a plot of a draw with Poission data: [image: example]

Comment: yea this is what I was getting at although I did it poorly